# How to unwind (multi-level return) the stack without catch/try/raise?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8, stack-unwinding

I would like to unwind the stack to an arbitrary level when `catch`/`try` is not available (i.e., the code to which I'm unwinding is out of my control). Is this possible?

For example, in testing, I would like to have my tests call a method that checks for prerequisites, and unwinds to the caller of the test if those prereqs aren't met (resume at `caller[1]`).  Since the test harness is out of my control, I can't set up a `catch` block at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only other mechanism for multi-level returns is `callcc`, but that too requires creating the continuation at a level that's out of your control.

That said, in Ruby nothing is really out of your control: you could alias the method in the test framework and add any code you'd like.

Comment: Really?  I didn't think it was possibly to alias across classes.

Comment: Sure, classes are open, you can change practically anything.